# Probability -You roll four 6-sided dice three times

Tags: probability, dice

You roll four $6$-sided dice three times.

What is the probability none of the dice in any roll came up as $4$?

I'm thinking about:
$$\left(\left(5/6\right)^4\right)^3\approx 0.1121$$

please let me know,

Comment: Correct. Anyhow, in this context there is no essential difference between rolling four dices 3 times and rolling one die 12 times (or rolling twelve dices 1 time).

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: In former comment "dice" of course (instead of "dices"). Deeply ashamed... I will never learn (sigh).

Answer (score 3):

Throwing at the same time has no effect if you're looking at the values of individual dice, so it's as if you throw $12$ times with a single die and want no $4$ to occur, which is indeed $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{12}$ as you have.